# What percentage of Android devices has reasonable OpenGL performance?

Tags: android, opengl-es, statistics

There are many low-end Android devices that have really miserable OpenGL performance, like the HTC Wildfire. How can I figure out what percentage of the users has such devices with bad OpenGL performance?

Comment: Here is a benchmark of 3D Graphics performance on different devices: http://www.androidbenchmark.net/g3dmark_chart.html

Answer (score 1):

These two links should help:

[Android screens and densities](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html)

[Android Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Usually, those with older versions of android (1.x) and small screen sizes are the ones with low-end hardware.

Comment: According to that data, the percentage of non-OpenGL devices would be very low, about 1%. Considering that there are quite a few low-end devices on the market right now, and that they sell quite well, this is hard to believe.

Comment: Looking at the stats of one of my apps (over 750k downloads), I see that about 7% are small-screen phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't figure that out, *unless* you have accurate statistics.

I'm recommending (instead of trusting statistics) that you should have a target device as your goal when you're developing. For example -> *G1, Hero, Nexus One, Nexus S* etc...

Make your application work on the target device and after that you can continue building on your application based on its behaviour from your target device.

Answer (score 0):

Think of android game development like PC game development. If the user's device is slower than the device you developed for, make sure you have a settings implementation that allows them to reduce the quality of the game.

Creating a little benchmark would help too, just run the camera through a typical scenario in the game and assess the fps at the end to decide on quality.

It doesn't even need to be that complex, just 3 levels of quality maybe, based on lighting/textures: low, medium, high.